# How do you organize the files for your latex documents?

Tags: folders, workflow

When writing a large document with lots of figures, so far I took it that LaTeX-users mostly organize their project's content like this:

```
/settings/00-settings-total.tex
/settings/font-settings.text
/settings/hyperref-settings.tex

/images/chap1/picname1.jpg
/images/chap2/namepic1.jpg
/images/chap2/namepic2.jpg
and so forth...

/text/chap1/00-c01-total.tex
/text/chap1/c01s01.tex
/text/chap1/c01s02.tex
and so forth...
```

Would anyone happen to have experience with other possibilities, say all content relating to one chapter in the respective folder? The folder structure could look like this then:

```
/settings/00-settings-tota.tex
...    
/chap1/00-c01-total.tex
/chap1/c01s01.tex
/chap1/c01s02.tex
/chap1/picname.jpg
/chap1/namename.jpg
/chap2/00-and so forth...
```

Does anyone of you work with the second method? Are they some significant aspects which made you adapt to it, or some drawbacks of the "traditional" way?

I am aware that the question appears to be aiming for subjective opinions but I'd like to try and get an impression before migrating and trying it out long-term.

Comment: Looks like a good approach. I usually generate my pictures (with TikZ) and since I only have very few other pictures, I put them all in the same directory.

Comment: I usually keep the figures in a subfolder and the tex files in the main folder (same folder as the main file). I think is becomes overly complicated to organize it in the manner you lay out above.

Comment: daleif, how many files in the main directory do you have then? Or do you not split the files up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a modified version of the first approach:
so my master folder might contain

```
master.tex
refs.bib
my_utils.sty
chap_theory/
chap_theory/chap_theory.tex
chap_theory/figures/
chap_theory/figures/fig_theory_example.svg
chap_theory/figures/fig_theory_example.pdf
chap_theory/figures/fig_theory_example2.tex
chap_theory/tables/
chap_theory/tables/tab_theory_example.tex
```

then my figure or table labels match the filename of the figure or table in question (without extension).

Note that I use no numbering in the folder/file names (unless the figure was something like `fig_theory_2_cats.png` of course).

Because most of my figures are .svg converted on the fly to .pdf (with a few .png and tikz) I have rather a lot of files in my figure folders, hence wanting to keep them separate.

Comment: I'd say it's rather related to the second version, but thanks for sharing. Yeah I suppose it's better the keep text and images seperate.

Comment: I guess it's somewhere between the 2 - to me it was an inversion of the layers in the first.  No doubt someone will point out the downsides soon.