# Producing a Table in the main file from other file containing multiple tables

Tags: tables

I want to create a separate file for tables so that the main latex file doesn't get cluttered.  I know I can define tables in new file and add the same file in the main file using input{Tables.tex}. However, I am not sure how can I ask for/produce (not refer) the tables using the labels of tables in the main document? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: typesetting of tables and `\label`/`\ref` are unaffected by `\input`. The processing is identical whether the code is in one file or many.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand, but my question is how do I "produce" not refer a file in main document?

Comment: I can not guess what you mean by "produce"

Comment: As always, the question should have a full example code, so we don't have to try to guess what you mean from a description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the file tables.tex containing the tables

```
\newcommand{\firsttable}{% no arguments
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
\hline
This & is & a \\
stupid & table. & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{First}
\end{center}
\end{table}}

\newcommand{\secondtable}{% no arguments
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{ccc}
This & is & another \\
stupid & table.
\end{tabular}}
\caption{Second}
\end{center}
\end{table}}
```

Here is the main file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\input{tables}% file containing cammands

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\firsttable
\lipsum[2]
\secondtable
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Note: It is easier to debug tables in the text before turning them into commands.

Answer (score 0):

What I do (using `threeparttable`) is to put the entire threeparttable in the table.tex file.   This includes the caption.  I always put the `\label` inside the `\caption` - I've never had a problem this way and it saves me forgetting. The label is the same as the filename so that makes crossreferencing easy.

My main .tex file then includes:

```
\begin{table}
  \input{table.tex}
\end{table}
This is some text that refers to table~\ref{tab_table}.
```

while my table file has
    \caption{\label{tab_table}This is a table}
    \begin{tabular}
    ...
    \end{tabular}

in it.

The behaviour would then be exactly as if the entire contents of table.tex had been typed in at the location where it is `\input` in the master file.

There are various tools for producing tables without typing or remembering all the syntax - but these aren't affected by using `\input`.  Your editor may include something, or there's a plugin for openoffice, for example.

Comment: Great. I understand. But let say, I have multiple tables in table.tex, and of course I want all of them to appear at different places. How does it work then?

Comment: @sumit: it doesn't work -- (la)tex doesn't have an internal script engine.  otoh, you could switch to lualatex ... but probably not recommendable at this stage.

Comment: I'd split table.tex into multiple files: tables_properties.tex, table_results.tex, etc. (note descriptive names, no spaces and not numbered as they would be in the final document.  What's your reason for putting multiple tables in 1 file? You can always put 1 table per file, multiple files in a subfolder of the one containing the master file (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163618/28808 - a previous answer related to this last point)

Comment: You could create commands (using    \newcommand) to produce the tables.  These commands can then be stored in a separate file to be read using    \input in the preamble.  The actual tables would not be created until you execute (expand) the commands.

Comment: @JohnKormylo can you please show me an example to do the same. Thanks.